# Priority Queue has no member named top()?

Tags: c++, templates, stl, priority-queue, comparator

Here is my comparator class:

```
template <class T>
class EdgeComparator{
    public:
        bool operator()(std::pair<Edge<T>, int>& lhs, std::pair<Edge<T>, int>& rhs) const{
            return lhs.second <= rhs.second;
        }
};
```

Here is my priority queue init:

```
//Initialize the priority queue
std::priority_queue<
    std::pair<Edge<T>,int>,
    std::vector<std::pair<Edge<T>,int>,
    EdgeComparator<T>> 
> pQueue;
```

Here is where the error occurs--after a stream of weird error messages about the precompiler:

```
std::pair<Edge<T>, int> topEdge = pQueue.top();
./Prim.cpp:60:54: error: ‘class std::priority_queue<std::pair<Edge<int>, int>, std::vector<std::pair<Edge<int>, int>, EdgeComparator<int> >, std::less<std::pair<Edge<int>, int> > >’ has no member named ‘top’
         std::pair<Edge<T>, int> topEdge = pQueue.top();
```

ATTEMPT 1(Added const to Comparator params):

```
template <class T>
class EdgeComparator{
    public:
        bool operator()(const std::pair<Edge<T>, int>& lhs, const std::pair<Edge<T>, int>& rhs) const{
            return lhs.second <= rhs.second;
        }
};
```

Comment: try `const std::pair<Edge<T>, int> topEdge = pQueue.top();`

Comment: The first error message you get is correct. Subsequent error messages may be nonsense, depending on what the compiler did to get past earlier ones. Anything that comes after a stream of weird error messages should not be taken seriously.

Comment: If `Edge` is not copy-constructible (or its move constructor is not `noexcept`), then `vector` could fail to instantiate, and then `priority_queue::reference` could fail to be defined, and then `top` could likewise fail. As Pete said, see the first error.

Comment: Did my suggestion resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found one subtle mistake here:

```
std::priority_queue<
    std::pair<Edge<T>, int>,
    std::vector<std::pair<Edge<T>, int>,
                                     ^^
    EdgeComparator<T> > > pQueue;
                      ^^^
```

Looks like it should go this way:

```
std::priority_queue<
    std::pair<Edge<T>, int>,
    std::vector<std::pair<Edge<T>, int> >,
                                      ^^^^
    EdgeComparator<T> > pQueue;
                     ^^^
```

The first declaration doesn't build for me. Also, the error message speaks in favor of my suggestion. Look closely:

```
./Prim.cpp:60:54: error: ‘class std::priority_queue<std::pair<Edge<int>, int>,
std::vector<std::pair<Edge<int>, int>, EdgeComparator<int> >,
std::less<std::pair<Edge<int>, int> > >’ has no member named ‘top’
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

It's using the standard comparator `std::less<>` instead of your own class `EdgeComparator<>`. Hence, I conclude that the comparator template parameter is missing from your declaration, and that is because it's standing in the wrong position due to the missing angular brace.